How could you add a site to HSTS list on MacOS
Say you have a bank site that you want safari to go to always by https rather than http.
How could you pin that site to https if you are too lazy to type https:// prefix manually?
Alternative/shorter version of the question:how could I add a site into HSTS Preload list.

I'm going to hazard a guess that this would require disabling SIP at minimum! The HSTS list isn't meant to be modified. Consider that if you could add sites to the list, you could also remove sites from the list. There may be a Safari Extension that does this however?

Good point. I altered the question to clarify that it's an addition rather than alternation is what I seek though that would open a possibility of a cluttered list you can no longer fix.
